# Debugging app crashes in react native

Tags: android, facebook, react-native

I'm new to react native, and I'm trying to install the react native Facebook SDK so that I can do Facebook login with my app.

I followed the steps listed here: https://tylermcginnis.com/installing-the-facebook-sdk-into-a-react-native-android-and-ios-app/

The problem is that when I run react-native run-android, the app crashes immediately. How do I debug this crash? I don't know where to look for crash logs.
Running react-native log-android doesn't show me anything useful.

Edit:

I know that this a Java issue rather than a JS issue. How can I find Java crash logs?

Comment: Can you include any error messages the console is giving you?

Comment: I'd be happy to, but can you please tell me how? That was actually my question.

Comment: What specifically happens when you run `react-native run-android`? Do you receive no response, like does it just return the terminal prompt?

Comment: The react-native run-android command succeeds

Comment: Then do you have a virtual machine or actual Android phone set up to receive the message?

Comment: Yeah, I have a virtual machine running. When I run react-native run-android, it just says [app name] has stopped

Comment: If you can open the dev menu, you can activate remote JS debugging and debug the issue in the browser

Comment: I can't open the dev menu. The app crashes too quickly.

Comment: Anyway, it's probably a Java issue rather than a js issue. I sure would like to know where the Java logs are.

Comment: Then most likely it's a compatibility issue with the Facebook SDK and the react-native server. If the server wont even stay active and there is not terminal respose then it's something the Facebook SDK must be causing internally. I would usggest (unfortunetly) uninstalling the SDK and starting over, going step by step, it's just a diffucult issue to diagnose

Comment: Is there no way to look at the Java logs? I see a lot of people posting Java stack traces related to react-native stuff.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139111/discussion-between-joseph-fakelastname-and-megaboy101).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should build the app using Android Studio, then select the 'debug' tab at the bottom to see the console output

[image]

Answer (score 19):

To see Java logs, open AndroidStudio, and click on AndroidMonitor at the bottom of the screen.

I was able to see the crash stack trace. My problem is that I need to set a valid facebook app id in AndroidManifest.

Comment: In AndroidMonitor, there's a log which says "Please configure Android SDK", how do we configure it?

Comment: This tool was removed in Android Studio 3.0.