# React Native App Crashing With Android Emulator Without Error

Tags: android, react-native

I am new to react native and have created an app. The app runs fine in the iOS emulator with Xcode.

I have downloaded Android studio and when I run my app in the android emulator by running the following command in the terminal 'react-native run-android' the emulator runs with no errors. However when I look at the emulator the app seems to crash with no errors. I have no idea why.

[image: error]

Answer (score 1):

As they explain in this post: [Debugging app crashes in react native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43035925/debugging-app-crashes-in-react-native).

You should see the console of Android Studio to see the native crash stack trace.